# Codeigniter's Email Library, how to get to, cc, bcc values in send() method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to overwrite the codeigniter's Email library's send() method. Hence I created a library

> My_Email

```
class DV_Email extends CI_Email
{
    //My Overwritten code lie here
    public function send()
    {

        Parent::send();

        //Make an Entry in DB with to, subject, body etc
    }
}
```

How could I get the to, cc, bcc, subject , body etc parameters here ?

Comment: See https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Email.php (notably the protected properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get cc and bcc using the following:

```
$this->_bcc_array;
$this->_cc_array;
```

or as a comma separated value

```
$this->_headers['Bcc'];
$this->_headers['Cc'];
```

Check all the var on `CI_Email` as you are `Extending` the `CI_Email` class you can access all class variable as a native variable like `$this->VARIABLE`